# Classes hierarchy having pointer to themself

Tags: c++

I have a class A, needing a pointer to AA to work, required by the constructor. I have a class B inherited from A, providing to A a class BB inherited from AA. Example :

```
class A
{
  public:
    class AA
    {
      virtual void do_something() const;
    };
  protected:
    const AA* aa;
  public:
    A(const A::AA* aa_) : aa(aa_) {}
    void use() const { this->aa->do_something(); }
};

class B : public A
{
  public:
    class BB : public A::AA
    {
      virtual void do_something() const;
    };
  public:
    B() : A(new BB()) {}
};
```

Now, I would like to give the address of the B instance to the BB instance. Somthing like that :

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
    class BB : public A::AA
    {
      BB(B* b);
      virtual void do_something() const;
    };
  public:
    B() : A(new BB(this)) {}
    // It doesn't work beacause the instance is not yet created
};
```

Or something like that :

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
    class BB : public A::AA
    {
      virtual void do_something() const;
      void setPointer(B* b);
    };
  public:
    B() : A(new BB()) { static_cast<BB*>(this->aa)->setPointer(this); }
    // It doesn't work because this->aa is const
};
```

**How can I do that ?** Is there a design pattern solving this kind of problem ?

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't work"? It certainly compiles [after adding a few missing `public:`]. It would be REALLY good if you gave a complete example that can be run and shows the problem, rather than snipping out a few bits and pieces of code that clearly wasn't compiled before posting here.

Comment: Actually, I was really sure than my first solution doesn't compile and was not possible in C++. But I can't remove the answerd question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want BB:BB to *store* the pointer, then

```
    B() : A(new BB(this)) {}
```

should work just fine.

If you want it to *use* the pointer, then your best bet is to store the pointer in the constructor, and use it in a second function like this:

```
   B() : A(new BB(this)) { static_cast<const BB*>(this->aa)->UseStoredThis();
```

That assumes you can mark `UseStoredThis` as const.  If not, then you will need:

```
   B() : A(new BB(this)) 
   { 
       const auto pcBB = static_cast<const BB*>(this->aa);
       const auto pBB = const_cast<BB*>(pcBB);
       pBB->UseStoredThis();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Making `AA::do_something` public or protected and `BB`'s constructor public, [makes your code compilable](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ab99895e578b888).

Refactoring a little you can get a nice version as well:

```
class A {
public:
    struct AA {
        virtual void do_something() const;
    };

    A(A::AA const* aa_) : aa(aa_) {}
    void use() const { this->aa->do_something(); }
protected:
    AA const* aa;
};

struct B : public A {
    struct BB : public A::AA {
        BB(B* b) {}
        virtual void do_something() const override;
    };
    B() : A(new BB(this)) {}
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4242bf5e9e80288c)

Comment: The comment from @MatsPetersson already addresses, what you have wrote in the answer. I don't think the question is about compiling the code by adding the missing access specifier. Apparently, OP is unable to explain the question properly.